# linux - enabling system user to login?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, login, user

This user was created using this command:

```
sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/user --group user
```

But now I want that user to be able to login. I can become that user using `sudo`, but also would like to directly log in using password.
I tried using this command:

`sudo passwd user`

It lets me add password for user. When I try to login, it logins but instantly exits.

Comment: Do you think you can get the picture of /etc/passwd now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can not log in as `user` because it is a system account, which is specified by the `--system` option. System accounts are for daemons or services, not for human users, and are therefore given `/bin/false` for login shell. If you enter `grep '^user' /etc/passwd`, you will get something like this:

`user:x:117:123::/opt/user:/bin/false`

To allow `user` to log in, you can use usermod to change its login shell to bash:

`usermod -s /bin/bash user`

Alternatively, you can also edit `/etc/passwd` by hand. You may also want to make some other changes to `user`'s UID, GID, and home directory location.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the user was created without the -m flag.

```
-r, --system
Create a system account.
System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their numeric identifiers are choosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their GID counterparts for the creation of groups).

Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.


-m, --create-home
Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.
useradd will create the home directory unless CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs is set to no.
```

Edit: Also, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36481/no-home-directory-logging-in-with-home) answer to another question.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like user is lock, try

```
usermod -U user
```

also have a look at `/etc/shadow`, line with user must start like this

```
 user:$6$SALT...
```

If the line is

```
 user:!!:..
 user:*:...
```

then account is locked.